# Is there a way to listen for automatic removals from a MongoDB capped/TTL collections?

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to get documents that were automatically removed during a cleanup operation from a capped or TTL collection in MongoDB?

Thanks!

Comment: One way is, on a capped collection you can use a tailable cursor, for a normal collection you can use a tailable cursor on a capped collection as a message queue for it. There are numerous links for pubsub on this site and on Google.

Comment: @Sammaye but this would give me newly added entries, no? I need right the opposite - removed entries.

Comment: Ah yea true, sorry, I wrote that comment really fast and just as I woke up.

Answer (score 1):

No.

(I believe you will find the _id's -- not the whole document though -- of the deleted documents in the replication oplog local.oplog.rs for ttl collections. But not for capped collections.)